# Row comparison in R

Tags: r

I have the below data frame,

```
    R_Number    A  
    1           0  
    2           15  
    3           10  
    4           11  
    5           12  
    6           18  
    7           19  
    8           15  
    9           17  
    10          11
```

Now I need to create another column `B` where the comparison of the values in `A` will be computed. The condition is that the comparion is **not between two consecutive row**, i.e `Row number 1` is compared with `Row number 4`, like wise `Row number 2` is compared with `Row number 5` and this iteration continues till the end of the data . Condition for comparision result is:

```
     if (A[1]>=15 && A[4] <= 12) {
     B == 1  
     }
        else if (A[1]<=0 && A[4]>= 10) {
     B== 2 
     }
     else {
      B== 0 
     }
```

When it comes to `Row number 8 and Row number 9`these rows will not have next 4th row to compare with hence the value should be `0`

Also, the comparision result of `Row 1 and 4` is printed in `Row number 1` similarly comparision result of `Row 2 and 5` is printed in `Row number 2`

So the resulting dataframe should be as shown below

```
    R_Number    A       B  
    1           0       2
    2           15      1
    3           10      0 
    4           11      0
    5           12      0
    6           18      0
    7           19      1
    8           15      0
    9           17      0
    10          11      0
```

Comment: According to your description row 6 should be 0 while row 7 should be 1. Notice that row 7 does have row 10 to compare with (you are comparing with a 3 lag: 1-4, 2-5 and so also 7-10).

Comment: @nicola Yes you are right. Sorry for the wrong interpretation

Comment: @ANmike so then row 6 is also 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lagging the variable and then computing your new variable should work. Something like this:

```
library(Hmisc)
df <- data.frame(R_Number = c(1:10), A = c(0,15,10,11,12,18,19,15,17,11))
A_Lag<-Lag(df$A,-3)
df$B <- rowSums(cbind(df$A>=15 & A_Lag <= 12,(df$A<=0 & A_Lag>= 10)*2),na.rm= T)
df$B
```

I tried to avoid `if` statements. The `Lag` function can be found in the `Hmisc` package.

```
> df$B
 [1] 2 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But `B` is all zero if I execute the code to the same dataframe `df` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make any changes? I copied my answer and re-ran the code and the output is correct. I've added the dataframe to the answer just to make sure. If you tried a different dataframe, could you specify where the error occurs?

Comment: only change I did was from`Lag(df$A, -3 )` to `lag(df$A, -3)`. I did this change because when I executed your code `Error in Lag(df$A, -3) : could not find function "Lag"`, error was thrown.

Comment: My bad, the `Lag` function is different from the `lag` function and can be found in the `Hmisc` package. Run `install.packages("Hmisc")` and then `library(Hmisc)`, then try my code again. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to @nicola comment, I tried to solve your problem as well.
I recreated your initial data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(R_Number = c(1:10), A = c(0,15,10,11,12,18,19,15,17,11), B = 0)
```

So I used an if statement inside a cycle for:

```
for (i in 1:(length(df$A)-3)) {
if (df$A[i] >= 15 && df$A[i+3] <= 12) {
  df$B[i] <- 1
  } else if ((df$A[i] <= 0) && (df$A[i+3] >= 10)) {
  df$B[i] <- 2
  }
else {
  df$B[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

With last edit I solved the problem that came up when the length of data frame changed.
Now you have a generic solution!

Comment: Thanks your code works fine for the current data frame. If I try to make the length of the for loop as variable an error is thrown. Like I tried to make `for( i in 1:n`. My data frame keeps changing and I would like to have a generic solution.

Comment: @ANmike it isn't a problem, if you try to use `(i in 1:length(df$A))` the code returns an error, but correctly compiles the data frame. Have you try to use the code with `(i in 1:length(df$A))` and then open the data frame?
The code works correctly!

Comment: @ANmike The error stems from the fact that for rows 8 9 10 there is no rows for comparison.
You can solve the problem using `(i in 1:(length(df$A)-3))` 
I update the answer!